# Source code on Nedry's workstation: real programming language/s?

Tags: realism, jurassic-park

There is what appears to be **source code** depicted on **Nedry's work station** before he shuts down the gates, I wanted to know if this belongs to real programming language/s? (so we can all laugh/cry at how deprecated it is...)

A quick *Google* found an out-of-stack [question](http://moviecode.tumblr.com/post/94130118095/jurassic-park-1993-nedrys-workstation-as-he) was already asked but no answers yet.

Also a related question: [Is the Unix operating system featured in Jurassic Park real?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/is-the-unix-operating-system-featured-in-jurassic-park-real)

[image]

**Zooming left**
[image]

**Zooming right**
[image]

*(Note: images I could produce given a 1080p resolution edition of Jurassic Park)*

Comment: Worth mentioning that the titlebar of the left-hand window is begins "NEDRYLAND :MPW:Examples." (possibly followed by "hyper"). MPW is [Macintosh Programmer's Workshop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Programmer%27s_Workshop) (a Classic Mac OS development environment), the font is Chicago (the default Classic Mac OS font) and the colon-delimited path indicates Classic Mac OS. As the other machines portrayed in the movie are Unix systems (SGI IRIX), this may not be a realistic screenshot but rather some mocked up.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, it all looks like real code.

The window on the left looks like [Object Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Pascal) code for Classic Mac OS judging by:

- the `:=` assignment syntax.
- The `NEDRYLAND :MPW:Examples:` (cut off) window title. MPW is [Macintosh Programmer's Workshop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Programmer%27s_Workshop) (a Classic Mac OS development environment), the font is Chicago (the default Classic Mac OS font) and the colon-delimited path indicates Classic Mac OS.
- The `NewHandle` and `GetHandleSize` functions are Classic Mac OS API functions (can't find an API reference that old online, but they are present in the [Carbon compatibility layer for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Memory_Manager/memory_mgr.pdf)).
- "Macintosh HD" and "Trash" icons in the lower right-hand corner of the screen indicate Classic Mac OS.

The routine on the screen takes a string input and produces as output a copy of that string with consecutive tabs and/or spaces replaced with a single space.

The window on the right appears to be some kind of shell script for source code version control. Possibly written in an early version of [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) as it doesn't quite look like a UNIX `sh`-style syntax. http://www.joecullin.com/site/2012/01/jurassic-park-source-code/ claims to have found the full file (with a description and Apple copyright notice) based on matching text. The path where the file was found (`... MPW/Examples/Examples/CheckOutActive.txt`) is also associated with Macintosh Programmer's Workshop.

The window at the bottom is a script for converting [Apple PICT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PICT) format pictures to resources, as would be used in a software build process.

This is, of course, all very generic and not specific to amusement park/zoo control.

As the other machines portrayed in the movie are Unix systems (SGI IRIX), it is questionable that this machine was even being used for actual development. Development for the IRIX machines would have been done on the IRIX machines, probably in C, using the [Workshop GUI](http://mobile.osnews.com/img/2322/sgi.png) or command-line tools.

Comment: Where do you see Macintosh HD and Trash icons? In the "SYS ICONS" window?

Comment: The code that's not Pascal looks like the scripting language used in MPW; I don't think it's related to AppleScript. The italicized fonts in the "SYS ICONS" window look like they'd fit in well in IRIX's GUI; at first I thought the lavender borders were also IRIX-like, but I must be thinking of Sun GUIs since I can't find that color in any IRIX screenshots.

Comment: @echristopherson Yes, in the "Sys Icons" area. In the larger images at the "out of stack" link, the icons and text are easier to see and clearly from Mac OS.

Comment: As for the AppleScript, that was just a guess - not totally confident on it. I see some resemblance to the modern reference, but I don't have a reference from that era to compare to.

Comment: *"This is, of course, all very generic and not specific to amusement park/zoo control."* - which is why the dinosaurs escaped(!)

Comment: Noooo! This destroys my favorite conspiracy theory: in movies, good guys always use apple, bad guys use wintel.

Comment: The font is **Monaco**, not Chicago.  Monaco is a fixed-width font and was MPW's default font.  Chicago is a variable-width font and was used in menubars and dialogs.

Comment: @nobody "The window on the right appears to be some kind of shell script for source code version control. Possibly written in an early version of AppleScript as it doesn't quite look like a UNIX sh-style syntax" - It is MPW Shell Script – http://wiki.c2.com/?MpwShell – MPW included a derivative of the csh shell from Unix. If it doesn't look familiar to you, it is probably because most people these days would be much more familiar with Unix Bourne style shells (such as bash) rather than C shell (csh).

Answer (score 10):

This looks like Delphi (or a pascal derivative) because of the semi colons at the end of the lines and also the `:=` assignment operator. Delphi is also a RAD language which would be good for building out their screens.

Edit: Based on the related question of the system running unix, Delphi can be done on *nix

**Note: Object Pascal (Delphi) is generally not case sensitive.** My examples are in lowercase while the screen shot is uppercase.

Here is a basic `if/else` I found from [here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Logic)

```
if (condition1) And (condition2)   // Both conditions must be satisfied
   then
     begin
       statement1;
       statement2;
       ...
     end              // Notice no terminating ';' - still part of 'if'
   else
     begin
       statement3;
       statement4;
       ...
     end;
```

if you compare the similarities to what you can see in the image, it's a match. `The if [predicates] then begin ... end` matches

Same for the `while [condition] do` example from [here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=While)

```
While sqrNum <= 100 do
  begin
...
end;
```

<strike>Also looking at the comment blocks using `*`, you can match them to this ([found here](http://www.prestwood.com/ASPSuite/KB/Document_View.asp?QID=101505))</strike>

```
//This is a single line comment.

{
Multiple line
comment.
}

(*
This too is a
multiple line comment.
*)
```

Examining the right file more the comments are # not * and it also looks like a build script or some kind of shell script, especially if you read the comments.

Comment: Or any other kind of Pascal dialect afterall, no?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson yes

Comment: Well, I for myself had written those keywords large or mentioned that it's case insensitive, becuase as it stands you code example doesn't look *the slightest* like anything from that screenshot.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I'm correct in my answer (or close enough). Delphi is case insensitive from what I found.

Comment: Sure, just that this wasn't clear from your answer. Someone who does *not* know that programming language (which we have to assume is basically everyone on a site about *movies*) looks at your code examples and can't see even a remote similarity. But at least you now mention the case insensitivity in the answer.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I thought everyone here came from SO :)

Comment: 1080p editions of pictures added

Comment: @DustinDavis actually that's quite an interesting hypothesis, I am not familiar with Stack Exchange's API but it would be interesting if it could be used to test it! https://api.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have a look here, some of the code seems to match.  https://www.mail-archive.com/fpc-devel@lists.freepascal.org/msg01884.html

Comment: I also see suffix `^` used for pointers, which is definitely an Object Pascal or Delphi hint.