# Is the Unix command used by the system analyst in Jurassic World 2 valid?

Tags: realism, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

The Jurassic Park franchise has always been pretty good at being scientifically accurate even with computers, as can be seen [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/is-the-unix-operating-system-featured-in-jurassic-park-real?noredirect=1&lq=1). Jurassic World 2 seems to be no exception. At some point the system analyst diagnoses a failing ventilation system, and the command used looks like a valid unix console starting with sudo and using the standard `--` for option in command line.

What I managed to read was:

```
sudo dudecode --isolate
```

Is it really `dudecode` and an easter egg for those who read it? Or is this a real command like `dmidecode` which is a DMI table decoder? `--isolate` [does not seem to be an option for dmidecode](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode).

Knowing the kind of attention to detail in previous films, I find it interesting to see if its something that could really be used to solve a hardware problem using a software access? What would the real command used be, and would a real system analyst use it in this situation?

I realize it will be hard to have definite proof of what the command was (as the film is still in theater as I'm writting this) but a screenshot or someone with certainty would be nice.

Comment: +1 for taking criticism to heart and turning the question around with a great deal of effort and motivation. Nice work!

Comment: There is a `uudecode` command for Unix, but that doesn't mean that `dudecode` is invalid - it's just the name of a system command or program call from the command line - even if it's not part of Unix itself, the park will have custom code created for their operations, so it's entirely plausible that command/program does something to reset/reinitialise the vents.  If they stay broken after the reset, I'd presume they would send out a hardware tech to check for physical problems.

Comment: anyone else that reads "dude code" here and thinks it might be a pun?

Comment: Only 46 hits in google, so probably made up for the movie.

Comment: That edit is probably better fit as an answer or an ammendment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/itsaunixsystem/comments/9tyalu/its_still_a_unix_system_jurassic_world_fallen/) its :

```
sudo dmidecode -isolate
```

[image: Actual screenshot of the moment it happens.]

But after looking at [`dmidecode` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode), only the `-s` and `-t` option exists. So it would probably error out for `i`, `o`, `l`, `a` and `e`.

Answer (score 9):

It's likely that it might have been custom code that the park's IT had created, or an alias to the "sudo systemctl restart 'serviceName'" to restart the service/application that runs the ventilation.

There is no standard command in UNIX/Linux called Dudecode. There is a uudecode command in Linux/UNIX. It's function is to decode a file from 7-bit ASCII to binary form. Uuencode encodes it to 7-bit ASCII from binary.

According to the man page for these commands, there is no --ISOLATE option. Thus one can conclude that the --ISOLATE switch is fictional.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/uudecode

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-uudecode/

https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/uudecode/

Comment: There is no reason for the system analyst to know about a custom command used in an organisation he never worked for. Also dmidecode retrieve hardware detail and would be closer to what someone need to debug hardware than uudecode. Let's hope a screenshot stop those specualations :)

Comment: It's also Hollywood, though, so one could also conclude that they simply could've had the props dept (or whoever makes fake computer stroke programs) make a script that runs, and simulates command entry. Thus "dudecode --isolate" is something they just made up entirely to look good. No one actually bothered to research anything to that detail. 

My reply is simply the most-similar command to what the OP is referencing. "dudecode --isolate" is what he managed to see when he watched, so that's what I found to help answer his question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the scene where the character tries to enable the HVAC system at the 200 minute mark, I believe the command was:

> sudo dmidecode -t system

Which is a real command that prints system-type DMI/SMBIOS data (you can learn more about the command in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode)), for example the serial number of the motherboard and such. I'm not sure how that information was useful in that situation, but yep, it is a real command, and yes, **it's a unix system!**.

The other commands typed were also real-ish, for example he first tries to log into a serwer via the `ssh` command twice, first time getting an error (a weird one, might be fake), the second getting a standard warning about server key authenticity. Then also he ran `ls- all`, which is almost real (the real command would be `ls --all`, which would print all files in current working directory).

Comment: I found a screenshot, sadly the command in the film was invalid (see edited question) :(